# Default method in Controllers for MVC framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any default method that we can set in MVC controllers? I am trying to debug a code and one method is being called (public HttpResponseMessage GetBySpecification) for the first time when controller is called; from where this method is passed I am not able to figure that. URI and get is being passed to controller.
Please help

Comment: Use the debugger and stack trace to see where the call is coming from or right click on the name of the method and "Find all references" to see what is calling it.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas : have used find all references but of no use. I thought just like Index method in mvc famework we can set other method too by defauls

Comment: if you have used find all references or even doing a plain search using find then there is no reason for that method to be automatically invoked.... Best thing you can do is place a breakpoint on that method and follow the stacktrace to see where it got called from